# what's the difference between tabSettings and tabVisibilities tags?

Tags: salesforcedx, metadata

I found that in Permission set visibility for tab is like this:

```
<tabSettings>
        <tab>standard-Case</tab>
        <visibility>Visible</visibility>
</tabSettings>
```

and in standard admin profile it is like this:

```
<tabVisibilities>
        <tab>standard-Case</tab>
        <visibility>DefaultOn</visibility>
</tabVisibilities>
```

What's the difference between those tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.permissions_tab_settings_ref.htm&type=5) lists our what is the difference between the values. From the tags perspective, one of then is used in Permission set `tabSettings` and another in Profile `tabVisibilities`.

[image]

Comment: This is very unfortunate from Salesforce point of view to change field name while rest of the access related fields are same from Profile to Permset.